# How to save id in database but to display username on the page

Tags: php, mysql

I have image upload system on the site where users can upload images. When user upload new image it's saved his ID in the table which hold images.

Now I want to make when other user click on the user who is uploaded image to load all the images from that user. Currently on the image is showed 
`uploaded by: 1` where 1 is the id of the user. I want to show his **username** instead of ID.

> uploaded by: username

table `images` -> `id`, `name`, `image_author`

table `users` -> `id`, `username`

This is the query that I use now to show: image, category and uploader

```
SELECT img.* FROM images img                                          
  JOIN image_category imgCat 
  ON img.img_category = imgCat.image_cat_id                                                                 
  WHERE img.image_active = 'Yes'
  ORDER BY randorder ASC LIMIT $start_from, 20
```

I've tried to add one more JOIN and to select username from users like this but I guess is wrong since it doesn't show any images..:

```
SELECT img.* FROM images img                                          
  JOIN image_category imgCat 
  ON img.img_category = imgCat.image_cat_id
  JOIN users usr
  ON img.image_author = usr.username                                                                    
  WHERE img.image_active = 'Yes'
  ORDER BY randorder ASC LIMIT $start_from, 20
```

UPDATE:

I know that must be usr.id and may be I didn't explain very good. When user add image in tables images under column image_author I store the id of the user. Now with this query when I display images it show Image_author: 1 because I select that column - Uploaded by: $row['image_author']. Question is how to show username instead of user id

Comment: Is image_author the authors ID or username?

Comment: show table structure

Comment: Please post MySQL error message, it will help...

Comment: Show also your php code..

Comment: Besides, it's strange to link tables on a username, are you sure you join shouldn't be `on ...author=usr.id` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you have your user ID stored in your IMG table, and you're trying to join on your user USERNAME, so MySQL can't join anything which results in a zero rows return...

Also add `username` in the requested values in your select clause.

Try:

```
SELECT img.*, usr.username
FROM images img
JOIN image_category imgCat
    ON img.img_category = imgCat.image_cat_id
JOIN users usr
    ON img.image_author = usr.id
WHERE img.image_active = 'Yes'
ORDER BY randorder ASC LIMIT $start_from, 20
```

**Edit after OP comment:**

With preceding request, you can access your username in `$row['username']` after fetching your result:
`echo("Uploaded by: ".$row['username']);`

Comment: @Zakariae / Mihkel Allorg: seems I've been too slow on my phone keyboard ;-)

Comment: Thank's for the answer. I know that must be `usr.id` and may be I didn't explain very good. When user add image in tables `images` under column `image_author` I store the `id` of the user. Now with this query when I display images it show `Image_author: 1` because I select that column - `Uploaded by: $row['image_author']`. Question is how to show username instead of user id

Comment: Ok, how can I be so silly. It's so simple :(. That's work perfectly! Thank you

Comment: Just one last question. When I click on link `userImages.php?id='.$row['username'].'` and go on the page userImages I get the ID `$_GET['id']` ... but how to display now the name again -> `That's all images uploaded by: USERNAME` :)

Comment: I think you want your script to get the ID as a get parameter, not the USERNAME: `userImages.php?id='.$row['id']` . So your script has the ID, it can send a request using this ID, and get all needed information from the DB.

Comment: I make it with sub query in `userImages.php`. The idea is to show `All images uploaded by: USERNAME` before getting the ID in userImages.php. So I make the query which select the username.

Comment: It's all ok now even if I'm not sure that this aproach is correct or no. For now working as I need. When I get more advanced will repair it :). Thank's

Answer (score 2):

when you join a table in a request you need to join it using the foreign key, witch I think in your case is usr.id, not usr.username, so the SQL would be something like this

```
SELECT img.*, usr.username FROM images img                                          
JOIN image_category imgCat 
ON img.img_category = imgCat.image_cat_id
JOIN users usr
ON img.image_author = usr.id                                                                    
WHERE img.image_active = 'Yes'
ORDER BY randorder ASC LIMIT $start_from, 20
```

Answer (score 2):

You had a typo, you joined the tables on `img.image_author = usr.username`, but you actually needed to join `img.image_author = usr.id`. Also you have to add the username in the selected items in the first row.

```
SELECT img.* , users.username FROM images img                                          
JOIN image_category imgCat 
ON img.img_category = imgCat.image_cat_id
JOIN users usr
ON img.image_author = usr.id                                                                    
WHERE img.image_active = 'Yes'
ORDER BY randorder ASC LIMIT $start_from, 20
```

Answer (score 2):

Your solution may be like:

```
SELECT img.* FROM images img                                          
  LEFT JOIN image_category imgCat ON img.img_category = imgCat.image_cat_id
  LEFT JOIN users ON users.id= img.image_author
  WHERE img.image_active = 'Yes'
  ORDER BY randorder ASC LIMIT $start_from, 20
```

Comment: Thank's for the answer. With your solution I get username instead of user id but the link to see all images from that user become `userImages.php?id=username` which is not accurate.

Comment: It's my pleasure John, Now you are closer to your solution. I think you have to first get Users.id from Username in  userImages.php; or you can use Sub query